# add range of number (1..5) in one column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert into a column a range of number 1 to 5

```
INSERT INTO public.npc(name, gold, info, id, quest_level)
VALUES ('test',200,'do_that',1,(1..5)
```

Comment: What data type is it supposed to be ?

Comment: Do you want to store all values in that range, or just the start and end of the range? If the latter, use a [range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your `quest_level` has the data type `int[]`

```
 CREATE TABLE public.npc(
    name text, 
    gold int, 
    info text, 
    id int, 
    quest_level int[]
);
```

In this case you could insert your values like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.npc (name, gold, info, id, quest_level) VALUES 
('test',200,'do_that',1, (SELECT array_agg(g.i) 
                          FROM generate_series(1,5) as g(i)));
```

In case `quest_level` has another data type, e.g. `text` then a cast is necessary:

```
 CREATE TABLE public.npc(
    name text, 
    gold int, 
    info text, 
    id int, 
    quest_level text
 );

INSERT INTO public.npc (name, gold, info, id, quest_level) VALUES 
('test',200,'do_that',1, (SELECT array_agg(g.i) :: text
                          FROM generate_series(1,5) as g(i)));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to introduce *5* rows, then:

```
INSERT INTO public.npc(name, gold, info, id, quest_level)
    SELECT 'test', 200, 'do_that', 1, gs.n
    FROM generate_series(1, 5) gs(n);
```